# Phalcon installation issue `"identifier (T_STRING)"'

Tags: composer-php, phalcon

I'm trying to install the Phalcon command on my Mac OSX 10.9.4, After run the commands

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git
cd phalcon-devtools
ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/phalcon
```

and when I typing the command `$Phalcon` I'm usually got this issue on the terminal

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting"identifier (T_STRING)"' or "variable (T_VARIABLE)"' or'{'' or '$'' in /Users/astm/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php on line 53
```

BTW, I'm using PHP Version 5.6.7 and I can see the Phalcon installed from the phpinfo page and this is my Phalcon details

```
Author: Phalcon Team and contributors
Version: 3.0.0
Build Date: Aug 1 2016 08:27:18
Powered by Zephir: Version 0.9.3a-dev-e716dbe641
```

and my composer version is :

```
1.4-dev (64b9423df3cf04034809781cb034470e61225190) 2017-01-19 12:39:26
```

so why I got this error and how I can fix it to run Phalcon command from my terminal

Comment: You have to use `/usr/bin/phalcon` command, or just `phalcon`

Comment: i'm using Phalcon command but usually got the error Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' or `'{'' or `'$'' in /Users/astm/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php on line 53

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where there were two different ini files being loaded. Calling `php -i | grep phalcon` showed nothing, but `php5 -i | grep phalcon` loaded it properly. Did you modify the shebang of phalcon.php already? If you can find the right command to call the php with phalcon loaded from the CLI you can replace the shebang path with this version.

If that doesn't work maybe the issue is with the version of phalcon-devtools? You could try checkout an earlier tag. I'm not sure if this is the problem though because I went through the steps of installing ext-phalcon, cloning phalcon-devtools and trying out what you did using php v5.6.29 and it worked fine for me after updating the shebang.

Comment: I have only one ini file, BTW I called php -i | grep phalcon  but nothing hapen I still got the same error

Comment: Do you mean nothing appears in the output of php -i | grep phalcon? Are you sure the phalcon extension is enabled for php?

Comment: yes, BTW if I downloaded Phalcon applications and running it under my mamp path it will work will, but from my terminal i'm not able to run any commands related with "Phalcon"  such as phalcon create-project or phalcon create-controller --name or phalcon model because the "phalcon" command giving me the error Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' or `'{'' or `'$'' in /Users/astm/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php on line 53

Comment: It sounds like you need to enable the phalcon extension for CLI PHP. Check which ini you're using with PHP --ini and enable based on the path that gives

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I found the solution by updated my PHP version from the terminal by the command 
`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`
then I used the command `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` to export my new php version and now after typing `php -v` my version become

```
PHP 5.6.27 (cli) (built: Nov  1 2016 09:10:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

then I used the command  `which php` to get the php paths `/usr/local/php5/bin/php`
after that I used the command `sudo /usr/local/php5 open.` to open the paths  then I downloaded the Phalcon extension from the [page](https://github.com/majksner/php-phalcon-mamp/tree/master/php5.6.10) and added it in the folder `usr/local/php-5-5.6.27-20161101-091321/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226` and under the folder `usr/local/php-5-5.6.27-20161101-091321/lib/' added in the`php.ini`file the extension`extension=phalcon.so`and now if I type the command`phalcon` it's giving me

```
Phalcon DevTools (3.0.4)

Available commands:
  info             (alias of: i)
  commands         (alias of: list, enumerate)
  controller       (alias of: create-controller)
  module           (alias of: create-module)
  model            (alias of: create-model)
  all-models       (alias of: create-all-models)
  project          (alias of: create-project)
  scaffold         (alias of: create-scaffold)
  migration        (alias of: create-migration)
  webtools         (alias of: create-webtools)
```